# Making asynchronous API synchronous

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am connecting to an API to get some data that is defined like this:

A client object `ClientConnection`, which allows one to send requests.
A IApi interface that needs to be passed to  the `ClientConnection` to receive callbacks.
Schematically it looks like this:

```
// defined in the API dll
public class ClientConnection {
    public ClientConnection(IApi api) { ... }
    public void request(int reqid, string reqdetails) { ... }
}

interface IApi
{
    void receiveData(int reqid, string ans);
}
```

Now, obviously this is a fairly standard asynchronous way of doing things: send requests through a global object, with a requestid, and receive answers tagged with that requestid.

I want to create a wrapper that is synchronous. What would be the most natural way of doing this? Is there a smart way of using async await, instead of using thread locking and stuff?

```
class MyWrapper : IApi
{
    private ClientConnection _client;
    private int _reqToken = 0;
    public MyWrapper()
    {
        _client = new ClientConnection(this);
    }

    public string getData(string reqdetails)
    {
        _client.request(_reqToken++, reqdetails);
        // what to do here?
    }

    public void receiveData(int reqid, string data) {
        // what to do here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't test the code below, but it should give you the idea. Basically you can use `ManualResetEvent` to be signalled when you receive your result (and don't ever call this without proper timeout):

```
    class MyWrapper : IApi {
        private ClientConnection _client;
        // here you store your requests
        private Dictionary<int, PendingRequest> _pendingRequests = new Dictionary<int, PendingRequest>();
        private int _reqToken = 0;

        public MyWrapper() {
            _client = new ClientConnection(this);
        }

        public string getData(string reqdetails, TimeSpan timout) {
            // if this is multithreaded - lock over _pendingRequests when you add\remove requests there
            // and when you increment your _reqToken, or use concurrent collection
            using (var token = new PendingRequest()) {
                var id = _reqToken;
                // lock here
                _pendingRequests.Add(id, token);
                _client.request(id, reqdetails);
                // and here use Interlocked.Increment
                _reqToken++;
                if (!token.Signal.WaitOne(timout)) {
                    // and here
                    _pendingRequests.Remove(id);
                    // timeout
                    throw new Exception("timout");
                }
                // if we are here - we have the result
                return token.Result;
            }
        }

        public void receiveData(int reqid, string data) {
            // here you might need to lock too
            if (_pendingRequests.ContainsKey(reqid)) {                    
                var token = _pendingRequests[reqid];
                _pendingRequests.Remove(reqid);
                token.Complete(data);
            }
        }

        private class PendingRequest : IDisposable {
            public PendingRequest() {
                Signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            }

            public ManualResetEvent Signal { get; private set; }

            public string Result { get; private set; }

            public void Complete(string result) {
                this.Result = result;
                Signal.Set();
            }

            public void Dispose() {
                Signal.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Let me know if it didn't work or contains some bugs, so that I can fix answer